# How to filter rows based on column value without using FILTER function in excel?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

[image]

Hi all,

I want to use a formula to filter the rows based on the name chosen in cell D2. From what I searched in google, I only can see people using `FILTER` function which is very easy. However, `FILTER` function is only available if we subscribe to 365 office. May I know is there any way to achieve what I want for non 365 office user? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you care if you get blanks or FALSE in the resulting array?  If not it's easy, and there are a few ways, depending on how many conditions you need to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Manage to find the solution.

Formula:

G5 = `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($C$5:$C$14=$D$2)*(ROW($C$5:$C$14)-ROW($C$4)),ROW()-ROW($C$4))),"")`

H5 = `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$5:$D$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($C$5:$C$14=$D$2)*(ROW($C$5:$C$14)-ROW($C$4)),ROW()-ROW($C$4))),"")`

I5 = `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$5:$E$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($C$5:$C$14=$D$2)*(ROW($C$5:$C$14)-ROW($C$4)),ROW()-ROW($C$4))),"")`

Drag down these 3 formula to the cells below and should work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, hiding the values different than `D2` will take care of your need.  I am using a similar macro for this task and below I modified it for you to hide the values different than `D2`.  It will start checking values from active cell and loop through until it finds a null value.  You can try it and modify it according to your needs.  Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut or put a button for it into quick access toolbar, if you are going to use this frequently.

```
Sub hideByD2()
Dim i, j
i = ActiveCell.Row
j = ActiveCell.Column
k = Cells(2, 4).Value

Do Until Cells(i, j) = ""
    
    If Cells(i, j) <> k Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
MsgBox "hide process completed successfully"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Say you have this layout (just the first two columns of your data, moved to a1).  Here are two formulas, one that contains FALSES (if you don't care) and one that removes them (because you probably do):

```
=IF(A4:A13=B1,B4:B13)
```

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A4:A13=B1,B4:B13), ROW(A4:A13)-3), "")
```

The first one is pretty straightforward.  The second one is very similar.  It just passes those results to SMALL, which will return the kth smallest value form the array *ignoring FALSE values*.  To get it to evaluate the entire array, you also send it an array of 1 to n, generated with ROW(), and since the range starts in A4 you have to adjust by -3 to make the array start at 1.  If you didn't want to have to figure out the offset, you could do this, but we're rapidly losing readability:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A4:A13=B1,B4:B13), ROW(A4:A13)-MIN(ROW(A4:A13))+1), "")
```

When SMALL gets your list of matching values (with the falses), it will a match for each number in the ROW array you send it, and if it runs out of actual numbers it will start returning errors, which is why you wrap the whole thing in IFERROR.

This will work for numeric values.  If you have to support any value, you can still do it:

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    B:B, 
    SMALL(
      IF(A4:A13=B1, ROW(A4:A13)),  
      ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A4:A13)))
    ), 
    0
  ), 
"")
```

In this case, instead of returning the matching values with SMALL, you will return the matching row numbers, then you will pass those to INDEX, wrapping the whole thing in IFERROR.  I used a slightly different method to generate the dynamic indexes:

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A4:A13)))
```

which will return an array from 1 to the number of rows in the passed range, but any of the methods to generate the sequence will work.

Comment: I would disagree that using `ROW(A4:A13)-MIN(ROW(A4:A13))+1` in place of `ROW(A4:A13)-3` is "rapidly losing readability". For the sake of a dozen or so extra characters, I would prefer a rigorous, dynamic set-up to an error-prone, static one anytime.

Comment: I would also prefer it, but it's probably more readable to me than some.  I think a lot of people start getting parentheses blind pretty quick.  If excel had a nice format ability for formula entry it would go a long way.

Comment: Also, his data had multiple columns, and I'm not exactly sure of his actual use case, so I can see this formula getting involved.  And he doesn't have LET to help.

Comment: Maybe instead use `ROW(1:1)` or `ROWS($1:1)` which is readable and easily understandable

Comment: Thanks Chris for your solution, is it possible to print out the output together with the name? I tried to use your formula, only Value been printed out.

Comment: Another issue I realized is it only works for values, if my `value1` is text, then the SMALL function is not working.

Comment: @weizer, when you say you would like to print out the name with the value, what exactly would that look like?

Comment: You can refer to my solution below, I manage to get the answer

Comment: I'm just going to point out that aggregate option 15 is SMALL.  So you are essentially passing the output of SMALL to INDEX, which is the same thing I was doing.  In the future, it would probably help people if you give a little more detail on what you are trying to do and what your results should look like.  The formulas I gave you would absolutely accomplish what you are trying to do.  In fact, they are the same as the solution you eventually adopted.